# Republishing to RPubs, Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle)

Tags: r, curl, r-markdown, rcurl, rpubs

AN ERROR OCCURS when I knit an Rmd into HTML and **re**publish it to RPubs. There is no problem with the initial upload or republishing long ago Rmd.

`Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) :  HTTP/2 stream 1 was reset Calls: <Anonymous> -> http -> <Anonymous> Execution halted`

I have tried the simplest HTML document. So, the error is not due to the file size.

````
---
title: "Republishing"
output: html_document
date: "2023-08-08"
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## R Markdown
````

```
> curl::curl_version()
$version
[1] "8.1.2"

$ssl_version
[1] "(SecureTransport) LibreSSL/3.3.6"

$libz_version
[1] "1.2.11"

$libssh_version
[1] NA

$libidn_version
[1] NA

$host
[1] "x86_64-apple-darwin22.0"

$protocols
 [1] "dict"    "file"    "ftp"     "ftps"    "gopher"  "gophers" "http"    "https"   "imap"    "imaps"   "ldap"    "ldaps"   "mqtt"    "pop3"   
[15] "pop3s"   "rtsp"    "smb"     "smbs"    "smtp"    "smtps"   "telnet"  "tftp"   

$ipv6
[1] TRUE

$http2
[1] TRUE

$idn
[1] FALSE
```

R version 4.3.1
RStudio version 2023.09.0+463
macOS Ventura 13.5.2
MacBook Air M2

**UPDATE** developers started to fix the issue: https://github.com/rstudio/rsconnect/issues/976

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the republishing issue.

```
remove.packages("rsconnect") #Remove Installed Packages
remotes::install_version("rsconnect", version = "0.8.29") #Installing a Specific Version of a Package
```

Any higher versions of `rsconnect` (e.g., 1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.2, 1.1.0, and latest 1.1.1) will cause the error regarding "HTTP/2 stream 1 was reset". After downgrading "rsconnect", RMD files with failed republishing will still not be republished. You need to upload a fresh one.